# monitoring Requests in php

Tags: php, web-services

I have a project in PHP and it works as a REStFull service, an android application constantly request some functions, I want to know, from the server side, How could I see all the petitions?
the PHP project is in a hosting.

Comment: You write code to do. We are not here to do that for you, especially since you've provided absolutely NOTHING of any use, like code, or database structures, etc...

Comment: I am not requiring code! I have my code! I just wanted to know in a php server how to monitor all the received requests and the answers! for that, nobody needs the database structure!

Comment: uh, rest is just http. you monitor it like you would any other http request.

Comment: When your PHP processes a request, log information about it somewhere. A file, the database, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are after activity log, your web server can provide that (Apache or Nginx) for example, otherwise, you will have to implement your own logging strategy in PHP (https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog can help you)

If you want to go further, you can use logstash alongside Kibana and Elastic to get you a nice representation of your service's behaviour.
https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash

If logging your Rest service is very costly in term of performance, www.gearman.org is a very good option to easily bring some asynchronousity in your application.